# How to get all the groups under enterprise account via Box.net api v2?

Tags: box-api

Also is there any api in v2 (c#) by which we can get all the users in a given group?
As of now i could not find any api exposed in the following sdk [box csharp sdk](https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2/). Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: The Groups API is not yet exposed by the .Net SDK.  I'll accept pull requests if you're interested in adding that functionality.  Also, if have questions about the .Net SDK specifically, please consider using the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2/issues) page instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The Groups API isn't yet exposed in V2 but is being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the groups for a user by calling GET .../groups
You can get all the users in a given group by calling GET .../groups/id/memberships